# Access to the playbackBufferEmpty property of AVPlayerItem using swift

Tags: swift

Is it possible to get an access to the `playbackBufferEmpty` property of AVPlayerItem using swift?

I tried following:

```
self.player.currentItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions, context: nil)
```

But get the compiler error message:

> Cannot invoke 'addObserver' with an argument list of type
>   '(DetailViewController, forKeyPath: String, options:
>   NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Type, context: nil)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue, here is the solution:

```
self.player?.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: nil, context: nil)
```